# React - How to update nested object from dropdown when using mapping

Tags: reactjs, mapping, semantic-ui, setstate

I have a React component that is trying render table data using axios calls, change the values of the state of nested objects, then make a PUT call in the end:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  objects: [],
  isLoading: true,
  date: new Date(),
 }
}
```

So initially I setState of objects during componentDidMount using axios:

```
componentDidMount() {
const { objects, date } = this.state;
axios.get('http://api/objects')
  .then(result => {
    result.data.content.forEach(val => {
      objects.push({
        id: val.id,
        name: val.name,
        status: 'ok',
        date: this.dateParser(date),
      })
      this.setState({ isLoading: false })
    })
  })
```

}

Then creating a semantic table on React:

```
render() {
 const { objects } = this.state;

 <Table.Body>
  {objects.map((object, index) =>
   <Table.Row key={index}>
    <Table.Cell collapsing><Checkbox slider /></Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{object.name}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>
     <Dropdown fluid button compact selection
         placeholder='Status'
         onChange={this.handleStatusChange.bind(this)}
         options={statusOptions}
         value={object.status}
      />
    </Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell>{object.date}</Table.Cell>
   </Table.Row>)
   }
  </Table.Body>
}
```

I'm also rendering a dropdown with different status options:

```
const statusOptions = [{ key: 1, text: 'Ok', value: 'ok' },{ key: 2, text: 'Warning', value: 'warning' }, { key: 3, text: 'Unavailable', value: 'unavailable' }, { key: 4, text: 'Planned Outage', value: 'plannedOutage' }]
```

And I created a handle function to change the specific object property:

```
handleStatusChange = (e, {value}) => {
this.setState({ object: {...this.state.object, status:value}});
}
```

Whenever I change the value of the dropdown on the table. It just creates a new object which renders a new table row instead of updating the specific object property. Any help would be amazing.

EDIT: added and fixed some code. Still having issues.

Comment: Is the state variable called `objects` or `object`? You seem to have an inconsistency as the former seems to be an array, while the latter an object literal?

Comment: I think you code when you change state should be like this (instead object should be objects):
this.setState({ objects: {...this.state.objects, status:value}});

Comment: I believe you should invoke `axios.put` in your  handleStatusChange, then on promise resolve, you should update your state using `setState`

Comment: @Chris I updated the state variable. It's going to be objects and then I map over the objects

Comment: Are you trying to change data for a specific object in the `objects` array?